# NextJS - Add <Head> Data on query parameters

Tags: next.js

All my pages are working with `getStaticProps`.
I want to make "If there's and q parameter on URL, then add 'noindex' to ".
But as you can understand, that doesnt work on 'prerendered' pages.

But I have to find a way.

I need to add 'noindex' to all my 'shop?q=blabla' pages.

On _app.js I did like that:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter()
  ...
  
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Head>
      ...
        {router.query.q ? <meta name="robots" content="noindex"></meta> : '' } 
      ...
```

But not working on `getStaticProps` pages.
Is there any advice about it?

How can I automatically add 'noindex' to all of the 'q' parametered pages?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to create two different pages. One for the basic non query routing and the other for dynamic routing and use getStaticPaths for the latter.

[nextjs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#with-url-object)